# Run script in all tabs of a sheet except for the first few

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to find solutions for this for a few days now and can't seem to get anything to work.

The script below shows/hides columns in the tabs and works perfectly in the named sheet. I just need it to run through all of the tabs, **except for the first few**,and be applied in them too.

I just don't understand how it all works so am getting stuck.

All help hugely appreciated!!!!!!

```
function hidecolumns() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Jun 2025 2HR');
var first_row = sh.getRange(2,1,1,sh.getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat();
first_row.forEach((fr,i)=>{
 if(fr==0){
 sh.hideColumns(i+1);
 }
 else {
  sh.showColumns(i+1);
 }
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Running the function for all but a few sheets and all columns of each sheet

```
function hidecolumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const xsh = ["Sheet0", "Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
  ss.getSheets().filter(s => !~xsh.indexOf(s.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    sh.getRange(2, 1, 1, sh.getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat().forEach((fr, i) => {
      if (fr == 0) {
        sh.hideColumns(i + 1);
      }
      else {
        sh.showColumns(i + 1);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am getting the error "Exception: You can't hide all the columns on the sheet. (line 5, file "Hide/Show Columns")

Comment: We I think think message is clear "you can hide all of the columns on the sheet"  and that's a function of your content  I don't have your content

Comment: function hidecolumns() {
  
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var totalSheets = sheets.length;

  for(var i=3;i<totalSheets;i++)
  {
  var first_row = sheets[i].getRange(3,1,1,sheets[i].getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat();
  
  first_row.forEach((fr,j)=>{
  if(fr==0){
  sheets[i].hideColumns(j+1);
  }
  else {
  sheets[i].showColumns(j+1);
  }
  })
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

This script cycles through all the tabs, after the third, and works perfectly. The main issue is there are over 100 tabs. Ideally it would cycle through tabs 4-12 and then 80-the end, which would make it less time consuming to run. Can i just change i<totalsheets to i<13,i>79 ??

```
function hidecolumns() {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var totalSheets = sheets.length;

  for(var i=3;i<totalSheets;i++)
  {
  var first_row = 
sheets[i].getRange(3,1,1,sheets[i].getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat();

  first_row.forEach((fr,j)=>{
  if(fr==0){
  sheets[i].hideColumns(j+1);
  }
  else {
  sheets[i].showColumns(j+1);
  }
  })
  }
}`
```